# PreloadJS not working on Angular (createjs-module)

Tags: angular, createjs, preloadjs

I'm having an issue with angular & createjs-module.

The createjs-module is working, as you can see on the code, shape methods and tweens are working (I can visualize it on browser successfully):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs-module

But when I try to use the official docs from createjs to start preloading and using images, nothing happens:

http://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html

The queue does not load. I put a console log at the end of the "ngOnInit" that does work, but no event is dispatched from the "queue" object.
I don't see any error on the code, and I don't see any error/warning on the console.

code:

`import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as createjs from 'createjs-module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomp',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.css']
})
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

  public stage;

  public queue;

  public queueManifest = [
    {id:"header",  src:"header.png"},
    {id:"body",  src:"body.png"},
    {id:"footer",  src:"footer.png"}
    ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ///THIS CODE WORKS!
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.stage);

    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
    circle.x = 10;
    circle.y = 10;
    this.stage.addChild(circle);

    createjs.Tween.get(circle, { loop: true })
    .to({ x: 400 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
    .to({ alpha: 0, y: 175 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
    .to({ alpha: 0, y: 225 }, 100)
    .to({ alpha: 1, y: 200 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
    .to({ x: 100 }, 800, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));

    this.stage.update();

    ///THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK!
    this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
    this.queue.on("progress", this.queueProgress, this);
    this.queue.on("complete", this.queueComplete, this);
    this.queue.on("error", this.queueError, this);
    this.queue.loadManifest(this.queueManifest);

    ///THIS LINE IS ON CONSOLE!
    console.log("queue START");
  }
  ///NONE OF THIS IS DISPATCHING
  public queueProgress()
  {
    console.log("queue progress");
  }
  public queueError()
  {
    console.log("queue error");
  }
  public queueComplete()
  {
    console.log("queue finished");
  }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to declare `createJs` being an object of the window object in the constructor of your component?

I had some problems with preload js on my Angular 2 project with Angular CLI and I figure out that inside the process of the preload a method called **_isCanceled** try to process with a **window.createjs** object and because of this, the whole event process was being always stopped. But in my project, the createjs object was not declared as an object of the window. So, I tried this:

```
constructor()
{   
    (<any>window).createjs = createjs;
    this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
}
```

Comment: This also fixes problems with webpack, typescript and ES6 modules. I have no idea why it works but it works.

Answer (score 0):

With modern **javascript/typescript**, the `preloadjs` package is maybe not so essential?

I've been successful with `Promise.then()`

```
static
loadImage(url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const img: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
        img.onload=(evt => res(img));
        img.onerror=(() => rej("failed to load "+url));
        img.src = url; // start loading
    });
}
loadImage(url).then((img) => processImage(img))
```